# Can't set model in Asynchronous Function - Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have the view

```
class FoursquareSearch.Views.Origin extends Backbone.View

events:
    'change [name=origin]': 'setOrigin'
    'click [name=geolocate]' : 'geolocate'

  geolocate: ->
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(@handle)

  handle: (response) ->
    @model.set(coords: response)
```

I am trying to determine the location of a device and then set the model with the response. However I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined
```

The weird thing is this only happens when its inside this function. For example if I use:

```
  geocode: (location) ->
    data = 
      location: location

    $.ajax(
      type: 'POST'
      url: '/search/geocode'
      data: data
      dataType: 'json'

      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) =>
        alert("ERROR")


      success: (response, text, xhr) =>
        @model.set(coords: response)
        @center(@model.get('coords'))
        )
```

Inside the same view it works, and it works well... However I just can't get the other function to set the model. I think this is something about it being Asynchronous. I am by no means an expert at this, I am picking up Backbone as a I go along, but this is stumping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#geolocation_interface) doesn't specify any particular context for the `getCurrentPosition` callback functions so `this` inside the callbacks is probably `window`; `window` usually won't have a `model` property so this:

```
handle: (response) ->
  @model.set(coords: response)
```

ends up looking like this when `getCurrentPosition` calls it:

```
handle: (response) ->
  window.model.set(coords: response)
```

So `handle` tries to call `set` on the non-existent `window.model` and there's your `Cannot call method 'set' of undefined` error.

Try defining `handle` as a [bound method](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow):

```
handle: (response) =>  # fat arrow here
  @model.set(coords: response)
```

Your other `@model.set` calls are working fine because `@` is your view object and that does have a `model` property.